# Chromecast Web Receiver - Change button location for Chromecast Google TV

Tags: javascript, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I've succesfully implemented a web receiver and now started customizing [ControlSlots](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_receiver/cast.framework.ui#.ControlsSlot) with some [ControlButtons](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_receiver/cast.framework.ui#.ControlsButton) like so:

```
const controls = cast.framework.ui.Controls.getInstance();
controls.clearDefaultSlotAssignments();

// Assign buttons to control slots.
controls.assignButton(
    cast.framework.ui.ControlsSlot.SLOT_PRIMARY_1,
    cast.framework.ui.ControlsButton.SEEK_BACKWARD_30
);
controls.assignButton(
    cast.framework.ui.ControlsSlot.SLOT_PRIMARY_2,
    cast.framework.ui.ControlsButton.SEEK_FORWARD_30
);
```

However, upon casting, this shows both buttons at the bottom-right side of the screen (edited image).

[image: current-result]

This is unexpected as the documentation firstly tells that `SLOT_PRIMARY_1` should be located left of play/pause button, and `SLOT_PRIMARY_2` to the right of play/pause button ([source](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_receiver/cast.framework.ui#.ControlsSlot)). But the pause button is not even centered, instead it's located at the start of the progressbar.

Also, looking through the official docs, I see images that have the buttons options in the middle of the screen. Like here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/web_receiver/secondary_image

[image: expected-result]

The image makes it seem that either it was at one point (in the past) different, and the buttons were centered instead of aligned to the right, or that it is (or was) possible to change the button location.

Either way, the question remains: is it possible to change the button locations with the [Web Receiver API](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_receiver) on a Chromecast with Google TV, or is there another component (not the receiver) that comes into play that should be changed (if possible)?